# How can I import records in MongoDb with relationship between collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I need to import data using a .json file, in the record I want to insert there is the relationship with Blog and Tag, to insert DBRef into the blog and tag fields I'm doing this way:

```
{"_id":null,"title":"462 Locust Avenue, Hamilton, Nevada, 7422","content":"Id sunt labore labore et nisi ad reprehenderit.","date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1577843940000"}},"blog": {"$ref":"blog", "$id": "5ce5539c07a6fa40b8b76651"},"tags":[{"$ref":"tag", "$id": "5ce594ba75a21c17dcc2d74e"}],"_class":"com.company.blog.domain.Entry"}
```

However, when querying the data, the data for blog and tag appear like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("5ce6e7bdf0888414e0d017f1")
title:"462 Locust Avenue, Hamilton, Nevada, 7422"
content:"Id sunt labore labore et nisi ad reprehenderit cupidatat aliqua. Ullam..."
date:2020-01-01T01:59:00.000+00:00
blog:DBRef(undefined, 5ce5539c07a6fa40b8b76651, undefined)
tags: Array
    0:DBRef(undefined, 5ce594ba75a21c17dcc2d74e, undefined)
```

In DBRef the first parameter should be the collection name instead of 'undefined', how can I change the .json to get the collection name after importing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Json file isn’t too big, why don’t you rename the undefined text with the collection name and then import it.

Or try this

```
mongoimport --db testDB --collection Blog --file Blog.json
```

Comment: I'm testing this file with only one record to solve the problem, after that I'll solve it in a file with more than 1000 records, so I want to figure out a way to import it and the record will appear `blog: DBRef (blog, 5ce5539c07a6fa40b8b76651, undefined )` instead of `blog: DBRef (undefined, 5ce5539c07a6fa40b8b76651, undefined)`

Comment: I imported your document and when I made the query I get the right result.

`{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "title" : "462 Locust Avenue, Hamilton, Nevada, 7422", 
    "content" : "Id sunt labore labore et nisi ad reprehenderit.", 
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T01:59:00.000+0000"), 
    "blog" : DBRef("blog", "5ce5539c07a6fa40b8b76651"), 
    "tags" : [
        DBRef("tag", "5ce594ba75a21c17dcc2d74e")
    ], 
    "_class" : "com.company.blog.domain.Entry"
}`

Comment: Have you used mongoimport or did `db.name-collection.insert(the-object)` ? With mongoimport not from error but does not insert, it only works with insert(). It seems that commands like Date(), DBRef() and others (I believe they are methods in MongoDb) do not work with import. I need to find out the correct command to create a DBRef using an object to do import.

Comment: This is how I did it for a single document and it was just fine. Server ver 4.0.2.

`mongoimport --db testDB --collection Blog --file Blog.json`

You may need to use `--jsonArray` at the end for multiple documents.